# How to send the login name and password using ajax get method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have this embedded device (which i cant modify, not my managed). It has API parameters which can be submitted via GET method.

But before that it popup with username/password. If i use the same URL in Google Chrome address bar it works

[image]

but if i use AJAX GET method then its failing as following screen shot.
[image]

```
var lummens_url = 'http://admin:9999@192.168.1.52/vb.htm?language=ie&';
var lummens_zoom = 0;
function button_lummenszoom_in() {
  if(lummens_zoom>100) {
    lummens_zoom = 100;
  }

  if(lummens_zoom<0) {
    lummens_zoom = 0;
  }

  lummens_zoom = lummens_zoom + 1;
  $.get(lummens_url + 'zoomset=' + lummens_zoom, {
  }, function(msg) {
    console.log('OK');
  });  
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**For POST:**

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'http://192.168.1.52/vb.htm?language=ie',
     type: "POST", 
     dataType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     username: "admin",
     password: "9999",
     processData: false,
     contentType: "application/json",
     success: function () {
         alert("success");
     },
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //Add these parameters to display the required response
         alert(xhr.status);
         alert(xhr.responseText);
     },
 });
```

**For GET:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://admin:9999@192.168.1.52/vb.htm?language=ie',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Then Hackers can easily view the password in the network tab of the developer tool.  I am right

Comment: I din't said this is the safest thing. :)

Comment: It's not safest and also only used in windows aunthentication! for Web auth its worthless

Answer (score 2):

401 unauthorized has nothing to do with Ajax. It means you are missing some sort of auth (token, password, etc). You do not have this auth set somewhere the server cares about (cookies, headers, path, etc) and therefore it is not giving you access to the data.

https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/http-status-codes/

If you are ever using an API and doubt the code you are using to consume it, takes a step back and hand-build the call via curl or postman

curl:

http://curl.haxx.se/

Postman:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en